# Multiple virtual hosts with Apache on Ubuntu (separate log file for each website)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, apache-http-server

I have configured one Apache instance to serve pages for several websites, using VirtualHosts. Each site has its own configuration setup under /etc/apache2/sites-available/sitename.

The final thing that remains, is to get each sites apache logs to be saved in its own separate log file.

At the moment, I have the following directive in each site configuration file:

ErrorLog /home/morpheous/work/webdev/frameworks/symfony/sites/nooshoo/log/web.log

This seems to correctly record errors - however, other logging information (like access errors etc seem to be logged into /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts.log

I want to be able to have each site log into a separate file - to aid diagnostics and analysis. Does anyone know what I need to add to my individual site configuration files to force apache to log to separate files?

I am running on Ubuntu 10.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CustomLog     /var/log/apache2/your-access.log
```